# How to clone repository with TortoiseHG located over svn://?

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have followed http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/3/22/use-tortoisehg-mercurial-with-svn-repository.html for configurating TortoiseHG over SVN, and it can successfuly copy repos over http:// ex. `https://theworldsworststackoverflowclone.googlecode.com/hg/`. Yet my repo is located over svn:// `svn://svn.example.com` - and that when cloning returns

```
% hg clone --verbose -- svn://svn.example.com .
repository svn://svn.example.com not found
[command returned code 255 Wed May 08 20:57:46 2013]
```

Comment: Well, it looks to me like that SVN repo can't be checked out with SVN itself to begin with.

Comment: With TortoiseSVN it's all good, that's what you meant?

Comment: What I meant was that I tried to `svn checkout` from the original URL you posted, and it didn't work. I just tried again, and now it asks me for a password, so I guess that was a transitory problem. However, it's weird: I used hg as a frontend to svn everyday at work up until two or three weeks ago, accessing the repo over `svn://`